# Why does this PHP program not work?

Tags: php, function

I'm new to `PHP` and was learning about `PHP` functions from w3schools. It said "PHP allows a function call to be made when the function name is in a variable"

This program worked

```
<?php
$v = "var_dump";
$v('foo');
?>
```

But this program did not work:

```
<?php
$v = "echo";
$v('foo');
?>
```

But if I do `echo('foo');` it works.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think your post got messed up.  There is nothing after "this program worked"

Comment: what worked and did not work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This feature of `PHP` is called ***Variable functions***.

The issue here is with `echo` which is **not** really a function but a language construct and variable functions can **only** be used with functions. In your first example `var_dump` was a function and it worked fine.

From PHP doc for [Variable functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php):

> Variable functions **won't** work with **language constructs** such as echo(), print(), unset(), isset(), empty(), include(), require() and the like. Utilize wrapper functions to make use of any of these constructs as variable functions.

You can make use of [`printf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) function in place of `echo` as:

```
$e = "printf"; // printf is a function not a language construct.
$e('foo');
```

or you can write a **wrapper function** for `echo` as:

```
$e = "echo_wrapper";
$e('foo');

function echo_wrapper($input) { // wrapper function that uses echo.
        echo $input;
}
```

Comment: @Shiki: `print()` would also not work. You can use `printf()`.

Comment: Also, if you really need to do this (can't think of a situation in which you would) you can wrap the echo in a function

function echoIt($string) {
  echo $string;
}

$v = 'echoIt';
$v('foo');

Answer (score 1):

`echo` is not a function! You can use `printf` which is a function and it can be used to print out something.

Comment: No need to shout! Although I do agree the fact is non-obvious and poor language design.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible issues, and you should address them both:

1. That feature only works in PHP 5.3, to the best of my recollection.  That's the newest major version, so you should ensure that you're using it.  It's very likely that you're not.
2. `echo` is not a function, but rather a PHP language construct.  You'll need to write a wrapper function that `echoes` what was passed to it.

Comment: Variable functions were introduced long before PHP 5.3. I do not know the exact version number though.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$v = "printf";
$v('foo');
```